# How to load python package for long time in memory (pywsd.utils takes lot of warm up time)

Tags: python

If I execute following function (lets say file name test.py) :

```
from pywsd.utils import lemmatize_sentence
def test_fun():
    print("Hello")
test_fun()
```

It almost takes 10 to 20 seconds to move to second line of above code. Reason it gives is in output :

```
Warming up PyWSD (takes ~10 secs)... took 17.033336877822876 secs.
Hello
```

I need to call test.test_fun() multiple times from another file (say mainfile.py) (more than 10000 times). Note that mainfile.py is called from another file main.py which in turn calls test.test_fun(). However it will take a lot of execution time in this case. Is it possible if we can keep the module test.py in memory until our mainfile.py has ended or until we manually want to release it ? I want to do it for reducing the execution time (so that it takes only 10 to 20 second to load for first time and rest of the time it executes quickly).

main.py -----(calls 10000 times)---> mainfile.py ----(calls)-->test.test_fun()

test.py is imported in mainfile.py and not in main.py. Note that I can directly import test.py into main.py but then I have to copy a lot of code from mainfile.py. Hence I want to know some solution other than that.

Comment: It will load the module once when you import `test` in your `mainfile`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Definitely. That is one of the possible solution. I tried and it's working.

Comment: That's not a solution, it's just how it works. So what's your question then?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I have elaborated at the end of my question. I can do it using import but I want to know some other method. Otherwise I will have to copy a lot of code from mainfile.py. import solution I already tried before asking. But I want to avoid copying code of mainfile.py into main.py.

Comment: You don't need to copy code. If you import (with normal python `import` statement) the `mainfile` module will be imported only once, `test` module will be imported only once and `from pywsd.utils import lemmatize_sentence` will be imported only once. I don't get what other methods of importing you need other then importing

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I wanted to do it without import. Like someway to load the test.py in RAM and then use it and remove from RAM when we have used it.

Comment: did you run your testing code? How long it loads it? Python remebers imported modules and if you import it again then it skip it and it should take only 10 seconds and you don't have to do anything. But question is if you `import` code or you use other method to `"call it"`

Comment: I just don't understand your problem. Why do you want to do it without import? The issue you've described in your question is not an issue with the import statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything.

When you import a file in python, it will import all the packages imported by this file too, and, when you call a function of the file you imported, the things you imported in the imported file are already imported. So you have the message a single time and after that you won't have any problem.